# How are new semesters managed in Moodle?

Tags: moodle

Currently what I do when a new semester begins in my Moodle installation, is do a mysqldump of the current semester database and then restore it to another database for the new semester, then I copy the complete folder for the current semester into a new folder for the new semester. Then I "reset" the new semester installation to start anew, without assignments, grades, and with new students.

It has been done like this for a few years, so now I have a dozen databases and a dozen folders, one for each semester since I started using Moodle.

Is this the correct way of doing it? I think there should be a cleaner way, each time I have to do this it takes a long time to create the new semester, and of course my server is going to be out of space soon.

Comment: There are some notes about that here : https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Year-end_procedures

Comment: There is no wrong way for doing this. End of year procedures are a matter of preference.